# Hidden movies inside camera

Tags: camera, memory-card

I have Sony Steadyshot dsc-w550 camera. The problem is I can only see the recorded videos inside the camera. When I access it via a USB cable, I only see photos. I tried to:

- show hidden files.
- access it from different PCs.

The only thing I haven't tried yet is to read the memory card without the camera. I would like to know the cause of this issue and how to solve it.

Comment: That camera has both Internal and External memory, can you access both? Which OS are you using?  Are you using the Sony software that comes with the camera?

Comment: Didn't tested card memory yet. There is no video inside internal memory. OS is windows 7 ultimate. Another pc has win 7 too. I have no software for it

Comment: Show us the folder structure of your card when you plug it into your computer

Comment: there is one and only folder inside DCIM <somenumber>/...

Comment: Have you tried to RTFM?